# Symfony 1.4: creating link to another application work very slow

Tags: php, optimization, symfony-1.4

Implementation, that I use - http://symfony.com/blog/cross-application-links

```
// apps/backend/config/backendConfiguration.class.php
class backendConfiguration extends sfApplicationConfiguration
{
    protected $frontendRouting = null;

    public function generateFrontendUrl($name, $parameters = array())
    {
        return 'http://frontend.example.com'.$this->getFrontendRouting()->generate($name, $parameters);
    }

    public function getFrontendRouting()
    {
        if (!$this->frontendRouting)
        {
            $this->frontendRouting = new sfPatternRouting(new sfEventDispatcher());

            $config = new sfRoutingConfigHandler();
            $routes = $config->evaluate(array(sfConfig::get('sf_apps_dir').'/frontend/config/routing.yml'));

            $this->frontendRouting->setRoutes($routes);
        }

        return $this->frontendRouting;
    }
}
```

All work fine, but first call generateFrontendUrl function execute approximately 1-2 second.

How to correct this?

Comment: Maybe because you have cleaned your cache just before refreshing your page?

Comment: @j0k, Unfortunately, it does not automatically cached. I still solve this with manual caching. Thanks for answer.